# USB real device interface not displaying in android studio 3.1

Tags: interface, usb, adb, device, android-studio-3.1.4

I can run my `.apk` on a real device and on emulators successfully. But, I am not able to view my Samsung J5 interface in Android Studio as I could see emulators. I want to record the screen including a real device interface in Android Studio to capture the actions. I have updated Android drivers (ADB) and all settings in my real device are perfect.
Same is with Eclipse, where I could see emulators interfaces but not the real devices.

I have checked all the related answers here but didn't find help.

Comment: are you seeing you J5 in when you run `adb devices` in a terminal ?

Comment: .apk that is App is running fine on my device, issue is just want to see my device interface on my laptop when the App is running. In other words as I could see emulator (AVD) interface, I want to see my device interface on android studio.